# How to change ShellContent icon programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, maui

## Problem:

I need to change the ShellContnet icon programmatically from the List that I get from the JSON file, all logic is done, but I can't change the icon when I open the flyout menu.

## Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first step:** Convert json data to viewmodel.

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize the json data and assign the value into viewmodel.

**The Second step:** Add `ShellContent` programmatically with the data.

Assuming that you've got the viewmodel , it should be a List , e,g `List<Model> Models` .

```java
foreach(var model in Models)
{
    ShellContent content = new ShellContent();
    content.Title = model.Title;
    content.FlyoutIcon = model.FlyoutIcon;
    content.Content = new MainPage();

    menu.Items.Add(content);   //menu is the name you defined on FlyoutItem in xaml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout) about Shell Flyout. I found three solutions from the docs:

1. Try Binding the Icon to the ViewModel Property. The ViewModel Should be set to Binding Context of the ShellPage.
2. Customize the appearance of FlyoutItem  by setting the Shell.ItemTemplate attached property to a DataTemplate:

> ```
>  <Shell.ItemTemplate>
>  <DataTemplate>
>  <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*">
>  <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
>    Margin="5" HeightRequest="45" />
>   <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"
>      FontAttributes="Italic"
>    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
>     </Grid>
>     </DataTemplate>
>    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
> ```

3. Replace flyout content with own content by setting the Shell.FlyoutContent bindable property to an object:

> ```
>  <Shell.FlyoutContent>
> <CollectionView BindingContext="{x:Reference
> shell}"    IsGrouped="True" ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}"> 
> <CollectionView.ItemTemplate> 
> <DataTemplate>  
> <Label Text="{Binding
> Title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="18" /> 
> </DataTemplate> 
> </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>  
> </CollectionView> 
> </Shell.FlyoutContent>
> ```

Comment: the problem in your solution is that I can't use the ContentTemplate property

Comment: Did you tried the first solution. Only try next one if first one does not work.